# Under what conditions do expected value and linear operator commute?

Tags: functional-analysis, statistics, expectation

Let $X \in L^2[0,1]$ be some squared integrable random function. $(X_n)$ is a sequence of iid realizations of $X$ with $E [X_n] = 0 $ and $E [X_n^4] < \infty$.
$\Psi$ is supposed to be some linear operator $\Psi: L^2[0,1] \rightarrow L^2[0,1]$.

I want to show that 
$$
E\big[\Psi ( \langle X_n, x \rangle X_n)\big] = \Psi \big( E [\langle X_n, x \rangle X_n ] \big).
$$
Note that $x$ is some arbitrary function in $L^2$ and $\langle a,b\rangle$ is the inner product $\int a(t) b(t) d t$.

To show the above is no problem if I also assume $\Psi$ to be an integral operator of form $\Psi (X) = \int \psi(s,t) X(s) d s$, but I would like to avoid this specific assumption.

Can I simply put the expected value inside the expression on which I apply the linear operator? Or are additional assumptions necessary?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You might want to specify the information set that you are using when taking the expectation.  Also, I think the finite fourth moment must hold for each $X_n$.  Then you’re looking for something like convergence in the weak* topology.

Comment: I'm having trouble parsing the expression. Here $x$ is the identity function on $[0,1]$? Then $E[\langle X, x\rangle X]$ is a number and I don't see how $\Psi$ can apply to it.

Comment: finite fourth moment is assumed to hold for each $X_n$, sorry for that typo. So we have $E[X_n]=0$ and $E[X_n^4] < \infty$. I cannot give many more details about the exectation apart from $EZ(t) = E[Z(t)] \forall t \in [0,1]$. $x$ is assumed to be some arbitrary function in $L^2$ and $\langle X_n, x \rangle$ is the inner product of $X_n$ with $x$. Hence multiplying the inner product with $X_n$ should give a function, so that $\Psi$ can be applied.

Answer (score 4):

Working on the assumption that you are using $X$ and $X_n$ interchangeably, the answer follows from a simple approximation argument.

Consider a random variable $X$ on a separable Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$. (We can set $\mathcal{H} = L^2[0,1]$ in OP's case.) Also, denote by $\| \cdot\|$ the induced norm on $\mathcal{H}$.

1. Assume first that $X$ is simple. That is, $X$ is of the form $\sum_{k=1}^{n} x_k \mathbf{1}_{E_k}$ for some $x_1, \cdots, x_n \in \mathcal{H}$ and disjoint measurable sets $E_1, \cdots, E_n$. Then for any bounded linear operator $\Psi : \mathcal{H} \to \mathcal{H}$,

   $$ \mathbb{E} \Psi(X)
   = \mathbb{E} \left[ \sum_{k=1}^{n} \Psi(x_k) \mathbf{1}_{E_k} \right]
   = \sum_{k=1}^{n} \Psi(x_k) \mathbb{P}(E_k)
   = \Psi\left[ \sum_{k=1}^{n} x_k \mathbb{P}(E_k) \right]
   = \Psi(\mathbb{E} X). $$
2. For a general integrable random variable $X$ on $\mathcal{H}$, separability of $\mathcal{H}$ allows us to construct a sequence $(X_n)$ of simple random variables on $\mathcal{H}$ such that $X_n \to X$ in $\mathcal{H}$ and $\|X_n\| \leq \|X\|$ almost surely. Then we also have $\Psi(X_n) \to \Psi(X)$ and $\|\Psi(X_n)\| \leq \|\Psi\|\|X\|$ almost surely. So we can apply the dominated convergence theorem to obtain

   $$ \mathbb{E}\Psi(X) \stackrel{\text{DCT}}{=} \lim_{n\to\infty} \mathbb{E}\Psi(X_n) = \lim_{n\to\infty} \Psi(\mathbb{E}X_n) \stackrel{\text{DCT}}{=} \Psi(\mathbb{E}X). $$
3. Now, if we assume that $X$ is square-integrable in the sense that $\mathbb{E}[\|X\|^2] < \infty$, then for each $x \in \mathcal{H}$ the random variable $\langle X, x\rangle X$ is integrable. So we have

   $$ \mathbb{E}[\Psi(\langle X, x \rangle X)] = \Psi(\mathbb{E}[\langle X, x\rangle X]). $$

Not surprisingly, a very general statement continues to hold. You may see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bochner_integral#Properties), for instance.

Comment: Thanks for your anwer so far but I am not sure if I understand it completely. I edited the question since I forgot to mention that $X_1, \dots $ are iid (or the sequence $X_n$ is iid). In this context I don't really understand the construction of a convergent sequence in $L^2$.

Comment: @EcSil, Forgive me but I am not fully getting what you are asking. Is it your question how to approximate an $L^2[0,1]$-valued random variable by simple random variables?

Comment: No, my question is not about approximation. I want to know, if I can commute the expected value and the linear operator $\Psi$, or if I need to assume that $\Psi$ is an integral operator. I would like to avoid this specification. So probably it was a little misleading to write about the sequence of random variables.

Comment: @EcSil, Sorry for late reply. My answer addresses that, as long as $X$ is an integrable random variable on a separable Hilbert space and your linear operator is bounded, you can interchange the order of the expectation and the linear operator. Of course this is still far from the full generality, as you can check from the link at the end of my answer.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, in my opinion.

Comment: Could you guys explain what is happening in this term, pls: $\mathbb{E} \left[ \sum_{k=1}^{n} \Psi(x_k) \mathbf{1}_{E_k} \right]
= \sum_{k=1}^{n} \Psi(x_k) \mathbb{P}(E_k)$